# How to disable map in arcgis javascript

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am new to arcgis javascript. I have created street map in arcgis javascript and also added graphics into that map.I want to disable that map not the graphics on that map.How can I do it?

**Example-**

I have added a basemap which has type of street and after that I am adding graphics i.e. line. Now, I want to disable street basemap .I want to show only lines.

Is it possible in arcgis javascript?

Comment: what you mean by disabling map ? remove its displaying( blank map ) !

Comment: I have taken basemap which has type of street and  after that I added graphics i.e. line. Now, I want to disable street basemap .I want to show only lines.Is it possible in arcgis javascript?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create your own custom basemap using(It would be a blank/empty service)
Then you would need to add that new basemap to the gallery widget

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemaplayer-amd.html

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/basemapgallery-amd.html

If you didn't want to use the basemap gallery you can also utilize the newly created basemapLayer with the setBasemap.  ie: map.setBasemap(emptybasemap);

Answer (score 0):

or you could just add your layer of lines, without a basemap, ie :

```
require([
  "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/SpatialReference",
  "dojo/domReady!"], function(
    Map,  FeatureLayer,
    Extent, SpatialReference
  ) {
  var map = new Map("mapDiv", {extent: new Extent(-178.217598382, 18.921786345999976, -66.96927110500002, 71.40623554799998,new SpatialReference({ wkid:4326 }))});
  var statesLayer = new FeatureLayer('http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2',
    {outFields: ["*"]}
  );
  map.addLayer(statesLayer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Its clear that you want to hide the existing basemap from map after adding the line symbol/feature to the map.

It totally depends on how you have added your basemap. Below are two different approaches to achieve this-

**1. Basemap is added as tiled map service.**

if you have added basemap as ***ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer*** the while adding give an ID or assign in varibale and use `hide()` method once you are done with your line graphics

For more details [click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html#hide)

**2. Basemap is added using only key of basemap**

ArcGIS JS API also allows user to add few default basemap using only their keys. 
click here to know the keys/Name of the [default basemaps](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1).

However if you are using the second approach then first access the basemap layer object in map and once you find out the basemap then simply hide that using `hide()` method of the layer.

Feel free to shoot your queries.

***Hoping this will help you :)***